# Reading from BufferedReader twice in java

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader

I build a Web Server in java, which I get request (as a socket) and process it.
I am required to first print the entire request and then process it on.
Here's my code snippet:

```
public HttpRequest(Socket socket) throws Exception
{
    this.socket = socket;
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    printRequest(input);
    // Do More...
}
```

The problem is that from this point on, the BufferedReader is in its end and I can't seem to find a way to get it back to the beginning. The `printRequest()` method prints the entire request from the BufferedReader with a `while` loop and `readline()` actions).

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: The homework tag has been [deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100/199903) and should no longer be used.

Comment: 'I am required to first print the entire request and then process it on.' Why? That constrains you to an implementation that could use more memory than is really available, and also adds needless latency. It would make far more sense to print the request chunks (e.g. lines) as you pass them on, one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the content in a `byte` array, and then use `ByteArrayInputStream` any time you neeed it:

```
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
byte[] content = new byte[is.available()];
is.read(content);
printRequest(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(content))));
processRequest(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(content))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Read in the request as a string;

```
String request = readUntilEOF(input);
```

Then do whatever you want with it;

```
System.out.println(request);
process(request);
doFunThingsWith(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually Streams are consumed as you read from them. Especially in your case where you read from the socket, the data is gone as soon as you read it.
So if you want to re-read a "Stream" in `// Do More` you need to create a new stream and feed it with the data you have received and stored somewhere.
Or, if you want to log everything which is read, you could just wrap the InputStream and do the printing as soon as the final consumer consumes the stream,

Answer (score 0):

You can't use BufferedReader to read the content twice. After the first read save the read content in a variable to use it later.